# Hibernate QueryException couldn't resolve property

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have this .hbm.xml file :

```
       Evenement.hbm.xml :

      <hibernate-mapping package="com.af.evenement">
         <class name="Evenement" table="TB_EVENEMENT">

         <id name="id" type="string" column="CODE_EVENEMENT">
               <generator class="assigned" />
         </id>

         <set name="causesAnnexes">
            <key column="CODE_EVENEMENT" />
            <one-to-many class="CausesAnnexesEvt" />
         </set>
         ........
```

and I've got this other .hbm.xml file : CausesAnnexesEvt :

```
       <class name="CausesAnnexesEvt" table="TB_CAUSESANNEXES_EVT">
           <composite-id name="id" class="CausesAnnexesEvtPK">
               <key-many-to-one 
                    class="Evenement"
                    column="CODE_EVENEMENT"
                    name="Evenement"
                />
                <key-many-to-one
                    class="Cause"
                    column="CODE_CAUSE"
                    name=cause"
                 />

                 </composite-id>
          </class>
```

when I try to delete an Evenement object with this line of code :

```
       Session s=getCurrentSession();
       tx=s.beginTransaction();
       s.delete(evenement);
       s.flush();
       s.clear();
```

when I run the above code, I get the following exception :

```
      QueryException : could not resolve property : causesAnnexesEvt.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate looks for a field called `causesAnnexesEvt` in your class `Evenement` but it can't find it. Make sure the field in the class and the column definition in the hbm.xml use the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The exception shown is not thrown by session.delete(). Either you haven't shown us the complete code (stack trace would be helpful, btw) OR it's thrown during session factory initialization (invoked from within `getCurrentSession()`?) because one of your named queries can't be parsed.

So while Aaron is right about missing `causesAnnexesEvt` property being the cause of this exception there's absolutely nothing in your post suggesting that it should be a property of `Evenement`. Search all your named queries for `causesAnnexesEvt` and see which one references it and which entity it's looking to get it from.